# couldn't upgrade to fedora due to error “nothing provides python3.8dist(python-magic)”

Tags: python, fedora

I'm using fedora 32. I did `sudo dnf update -y`

I got below error -

```
$ sudo dnf update -y
Last metadata expiration check: 1:24:24 ago on Mon 30 Nov 2020 04:42:35 PM EST.
Dependencies resolved.

Problem: cannot install the best update candidate for package lutris-0.5.7.1-1.fc32.x86_64
- nothing provides python3.8dist(python-magic) needed by lutris-0.5.8-1.fc32.x86_64
=================================================================================================
Package             Architecture        Version                      Repository            Size
=================================================================================================
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
lutris              x86_64              0.5.8-1.fc32                 updates              819 k
Transaction Summary
=================================================================================================
Skip  1 Package

Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

My operating system details are

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 32 (Thirty Two)
Release:        32
Codename:       ThirtyTwo
```

How can I fix this above issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can resolve issues like this by:

1. Uninstall the package(s) with the dependency problem, in this case `lutris`.
2. Run the system upgrade, in this case from 32 to 33.
3. Reinstall the package(s) you removed in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

It is possibly a recent [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1902391). Other users seem to have issues with this too.